# Excel Formula - 2 sheets, multiple references

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

So I have 1 Excel Sheet with 2 tabs. In Sheet 1 I have a column of numbers All Data. In sheet 2 I have 3 columns, Numbers, Count and Balance. I need a formula so that I can say: If X number in Sheet 1 Column 1 MATCHES Sheet 2 Number column then DISPLAY values from Columns Count and Balance.

Comment: What have you tried? Sounds like a `VLOOKUP()` or `INDEX()/MATCH()` to me.

Comment: I have tried Vlookup and I cant get it to work. Unfortunately I am not too familiar with Index or Match. I hate that I cant wrap my head around this. On paper it seems so simple. If This Number Matches This number then I need the data in these 2 columns to appear

Comment: It's hard to help without more concrete examples. If you have numbers in column A on sheet 1, and you want to match that to the numbers in column A on sheet 2, but return what is in column B on sheet 2, type the following in cell B1 on sheet 1 `=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$5,2,FALSE)`.

Comment: Thats it!!!! Thanks